# Parse Pathparam equivalent in restService

Tags: rest-api

I want to create REST URLs like `/contact/{contactId}/test/{testId}` and want to pull out the variable conatctId and TestId using a PathParam equivalent from Jersey in Apex RestService code.

How do I do that without manually parsing the URL as a String and parsing for each "/"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think there is an equivalent of the `@PathParam` annotation in Apex.  The Apex REST annotations are described here:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_classes_annotations_rest.htm

That said, since you will know your URL mapping from the `@RestResource` annotation you could roll your own helper class to put them into a map, then you could access something like:

```
public class PathParam
{
    public static Map<String,String> parse( String req )
    {
        // assuming URL pattern of '/name/value/name/value' e.g. '/contact/*/test/*'
        List<String> tokens = req.split('/');
        Map<String,String> tokensMap = new Map<String,String>();
        for( integer i = 1 ; i < tokens.size() ; i++ )
        {
            tokensMap.put( tokens.get( i ), tokens.get( ++i ) );
        }
        return tokensMap;
    }    
}
```

Then, you'd at least have convenient access to your parameters:

```
Id contactId = PathParam.parse(req).get('contact');
Id testId = PathParam.parse(req).get('test');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this rest request method to do this

URL is like :`/services/apexrest/AccountId`

```
RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
String accountId=req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

You can keep changing the increment by 1 or 2 to retrieve all the params .

Or other approach will be as query string parameter
 say your URL is like :

```
/services/apexrest/OfflineSync?utctimestamp=2008-10-5+12:20:20&syncgroup=inventory&isdeltaload=0
```

The code to get value of the parameter will be

```
RestRequest req = RestContext.request;      
    String utctimestamp=req.params.get('utctimestamp');//The time stamp is extracted from Request URI
    String syncgroup=req.params.get('syncgroup');//The sync group information
    String isdeltaload=req.params.get('isdeltaload');
```